# How to reuse component data item in Experience editor

Tags: experience-editor

I created an item `TestComponent-1` under my `Test` route.

[image: sitecore tree]

This is the display of my `TestComponent-1`

[image: test route]

Now I navigate to my `Test2` route through experience editor and add `TestComponent-1` item. This is the result

[image: test2 route]

My question is : Can we reuse item in different routes?

- If yes : How to do it?
- If no : Why I was able to add `TestComponent-1` to `Test2` route without any errors? The behavior I expected was that the `TestComponent-1` moved from `Test` route to `Test2` route

Maybe there is a key concept that I didn't understand, if so please explain

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can share content between components using *ID references*.

These let you:

- Assign a unique ID to a piece of shared content (in `component-content` or `content`, usually)
- Refer to that ID from another piece of content, as a datasource or referenced item

Here's an example of referring to content by ID in the Angular sample: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/cda6450b024d8fa801f88d0dac31ab335ab9ec06/samples/basic-sample-angular/data/routes/en.yaml#L31

And defining the content by ID:
https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/cda6450b024d8fa801f88d0dac31ab335ab9ec06/samples/basic-sample-angular/data/component-content/Welcome/SharedWelcome/en.yaml#L2

This assumes you're working in *disconnected mode* and importing the app to Sitecore. If you're defining your items within Sitecore, then there's nothing special JSS-wise and you can refer to datasource items from anywhere.